# SSIS to SSRS communication issue

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssis, report, communication

I have an SSIS package that retrieves a days worth of information from a data warehouse into a table in SQL Server and then exports that data to a flat file.
The package then generates a PDF report from the same data that was exported.

In order to export the PDF file, the report had to be created in SSRS and published to a URL the SSIS package could get to.

The package contains three connection managers, one to SQL Server, one to the Flat File and one to SSRS via an HTTP Connection Manager.

The HTTP Connection Manager allows me to create a connection to my SSRS instance and there is a button on that dialog that allows you to test the connection.

The connection tests correctly and I receive a success message.

I have done this exact thing in numerous other environments and it works correctly.

Some things to be aware of are, I created this package on another machine and copied it to numerous environments. Because of this, I use a configuration file to store many of the settings the package uses, file paths, login credentials and other things.

I also made sure that the connection settings were correct and that I could browse to the Report Server and view the report I am trying to download in SSIS.

When I execute the package, I receive the following error message from the package:
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC001600E ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC001600E): Exception from HRESULT: 0xC001600E
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSHttpClientConnection100.DownloadFile(String FileName, Boolean vbOverwriteDestination)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.HttpClientConnection.DownloadFile(String fileName, Boolean OverwriteDestination)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.HttpClientConnection.DownloadFile(String fileName, Boolean OverwriteDestination)
   at ST_6b197a6290df4aff91a6881078049a14.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

That's about all I can think of that would be useful, but if you have any questions, I'll be monitoring this thread for a couple of hours.

Thanks.

Comment: Execute the package how? Via BIDS, command line, as a SQL Agent Job, other (to be defined)

Comment: Via BIDS and as an SQL Agent Job.

Comment: Fails with the same error on both? Is the user that you are logged in with on the server and/or runs the SQL Agent Service/is the credentialed user for the SSIS Job SubStep authorized for the report server? Is it the same user you are using on the servers where this works?

Comment: The servers where it works are at various client sites so each one has a different set of logins for their environments. It does fail with the same error in BIDS and the Agent job. The login for this particular environment is not the account that I login to the server with as I have administrative privileges on the server and the account that connects to the Report Server has just enough permissions to run the job and view reports.

Comment: I decided to test something and made the account a local administrator on the machine just to see if that would resolve the issue, but it doesn't.